# Expression Func with List<T>.Select().Contains()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Here is my generic repository class method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Where(condition).ToList();
    }
```

And I want to call it like:

```
resultCandidate = _repo.GetBy(p => members.Select(s=>s.MemberID).Contains(p.CandidateMemberID)).ToList();
```

But when I try it it threw an error like that "Unable to create a constant value of type `StateInfo`. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

I should call the method like that. And I tried to `condition.Compile()` and it worked but not worked like what i want. Because it doesn't get the where clauses when generating SQL query.

Note: members is a `List<MemberInfo>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is ok. But you need to move the member ID list outside of the expression (that's what the exception message is trying to indicate), thus satisfying the *primitive type* list requirement:

```
var memberIds = members.Select(s=>s.MemberID).ToList();
resultCandidate = _repo.GetBy(p => memberIds.Contains(p.CandidateMemberID)).ToList();
```

**UPDATE:** Well, if it's so critical for you to call it exactly that way, then you can try the following quite naïve `ExpressionVisitor`:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class ExpandSelectVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Enumerable) && node.Method.Name == "Select")
            return Expression.Constant(Expression.Lambda(node).Compile().DynamicInvoke());
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

and use it inside your generic repository method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition)
{
    condition = condition.Update(
        new ExpandSelectVisitor().Visit(condition.Body), condition.Parameters);

    return Context.Set<T>().Where(condition).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yeah @IvanStoev it works. But I should use it in method because its a big project and I can't do it every part of it. It should be like I wrote

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way to make it work with the current EF requirements.

Comment: Anything to do on Expression condition?

It actually works when I use `condition.Compile()` but as I said it doesnt generate code with where clause but only select from.

Comment: If you compile the expression, then the query filter will execute in memory (after loading the whole table), which is worse.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Well can we do it without expression? By using only func? It has to be expression for filtering before load?

Comment: Yes, it has to be expression. If it is a `Func`, it would be the same as using `Compile`.

Comment: May i contact you? @IvanStoev

Comment: Can you share your email please? @IvanStoev